# Git author sometimes changes

Tags: git, author

When doing `git log`, I have different emails sometimes, sometimes it is my private email, sometimes my work email. How do I fix this so I always use my work email?

Comment: See wether this helps: https://github.com/alextercete/git-multi-user-hook.

Comment: @alextercete This seems a bit overkill, should not git take care of this? I mean it changes users, but I have everything setup already.

Comment: Git will use the repo-specific configuration if it can find it, otherwise it will fall back to the global configuration. Does `git config --local user.email` return anything?

Comment: @alextercete It does not return anything. I already setup the global one to be my work email, but my personal email keeps coming back.

Comment: So which email does `git config user.email` return?

Comment: @alextercete For some weird reason, it is my personal mail. I have no idea why. The only time I used my personal email is when I occasionally log in to view my email. Is the only possible answer that I mistakenly used my personal email instead of my work email?

Answer (score 2):

Configure the working copies:

```
git config user.name 'Simon Zettervall'
git config user.email sz@example.com
```

Or do a `--global` config if you use the same username and email for all git repositories on the given machine.

Comment: Note that you will have to do this on each machine you work on.

Comment: I did this already, but it will use "different" users when commiting. This happens in all my repos.

Comment: @SimonZettervall: So do it for each repository, or even before each commit.

Comment: @choroba Why do I need to do this before each commit? I already did this for all my repos. Let us say I have one repo, then both authors will be mixed.

Comment: @SimonZettervall: I probably don't understand what you mean. If the config exists in each repo, the global config should be ignored and it should never happen.

Comment: @choroba I only have one (1) repo on my computer, I did the global config once, with my work email. My personal email keeps coming in though but I never typed it (same thing happened on another computer). I did not do any local stuff, only global once.

Comment: @SimonZettervall: Do you mean new commits still contain your personal email?

Comment: @choroba Yes, it does. The same thing happened on another computer as I mentioned earlier, I find it unlikely that I mistakenly put in my personal mail instead of my work mail on two places.

Comment: @SimonZettervall: If you haven't configured git at all, it can use the default user settings.

Answer (score 1):

Git retrieves configuration from [several different places](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-config.html#FILES), so it might be getting your personal email from somewhere other than your `~/.gitconfig`.

You can check the value for the configuration `user.email` on every file that Git looks at:

```
$ git config --local user.email
```

```
$ git config --global user.email
```

```
$ git config --system user.email
```

You can even specify a file:

```
$ git config --file <file> user.email
```

Comment: The only thing that returned something was `git config --global user.email`. Weird indeed. Thank you anyway!